# Protect plug from damages

Tags: electrical, receptacle, cord-and-plug

The plug from my pressure washer was damaged while moving it, because at some point it was not tied correctly to the body of the washer, and I believe it was caught between the wheels and the washer or something like that.

Is there something that I could attach to the plug so that it could be shielded from damages when not in use ? Or maybe some kind of plug that have such a built in protection ?

Comment: how would a modification to an electric outlet prevent you from running over the power cord with the wheels?

Comment: sorry, I meant the plug.

Comment: ok, it is now unclear what you are trying to protect ..... is it a power outlet on the wall? .... is it the power cord that is part of the pressure washer?